# Function returns before await async finishes

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, sendgrid

I'm trying to send 2 emails through the SendGrid API. Sometimes 0 send, sometimes 1 sends, sometimes both send. It seems that the function does not await the promise. How can I fix it so it always sends both emails?

My function looks like this:

```
private async Task<bool> SendMails(string email, string name, string pdfPath, string imgPath)
{
    var client = new SendGridClient(_config["SendGrid:Key"]);
    bool messagesSent = false;
    var messageClient = new SendGridMessage
    {
        From = new EmailAddress(_config["SendGrid:Recipient"]),
        Subject = "Testmail",
        HtmlContent = _textManager.Get("getMailHtml")
    };

    var messageSecondClient = new SendGridMessage
    {
        From = new EmailAddress(_config["SendGrid:Recipient"]),
        Subject = "Second Testmail",
        HtmlContent = _textManager.Get("getSecondMailHtml")
    };

    messageClient.AddTo(email, name);
    messageSecondClient.AddTo(email, name);

    string[] fileListClient = new string[] { pdfPath };
    string[] fileListSecond = new string[] { pdfPath, imgPath };

    foreach (var file in fileListClient)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

        if (fileInfo.Exists)
            await messageClient.AddAttachmentAsync(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.OpenRead());
    }

    foreach (var file in fileListSecond)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

        if (fileInfo.Exists)
            await messageSecondClient.AddAttachmentAsync(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.OpenRead());
    }

    var responseClient = await client.SendEmailAsync(messageClient);
    var responseSecond = await client.SendEmailAsync(messageSecondClient);

    if (responseClient.StatusCode.ToString() == "202" && responseSecond.StatusCode.ToString() == "202")
    {
        messagesSent = true;
    }
    return messagesSent;
}
```

And this is how I'm calling it:

```
            Task<bool> sendMails = await Task.FromResult(SendMails(formCollection["email"], formCollection["name"], pdfPath, imgPath));

            if (!sendMails.Result)
            {
                errorMessage = "Error sending mails.";
            }
```

Comment: Remove `Task.FromResult(...)`. Just call it directly on SendMails: `var isSent = await SendMails(...)`.

Comment: @Silvermind I want the result boolean for error catching. If I remove TaskResult, I can't get the return value back. Is there another way to watch the return value?

Comment: And make sure the method that's calling `SendMails` is marked as async, and make sure the method that calls *that* is marked as async and awaits the call. And so forth, all the way up the call stack.

Comment: You can get the results of an asynchronous call. `bool myResult = await SendMails(/* params*/);`

Comment: Also, please be aware that SendGrid's mailing system is a queue, and therefor, the tasks you are doing only result in an entry in SendGrid's queue. Now they handle their queue pretty quick, but it still happens from time to time that you can notice a slight delay between sends. It sounds to me that that is happening here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're blocking on the async task:

```
if (!sendMails.Result)
```

and this can [cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead of blocking, use `await`.

And you can also get rid of the `await Task.FromResult`, which [isn't doing anything at all](https://twitter.com/aSteveCleary/status/1155827537232220161):

```
bool sentMails = await SendMails(formCollection["email"], formCollection["name"], pdfPath, imgPath);

if (!sentMails)
{
  errorMessage = "Error sending mails.";
}
```

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: In the op's code, the task returned from `sendMails` may or may not be complete by the time `Result` is called. Walk through the calls and especially take note of the return type of the `FromResult` call, and you should see the problem.

Comment: It certainly took me a minute... I don't think I've ever seen a *task* passed to `await Task.FromResult` before. :)

Answer (score 5):

`Task.FromResult` returns a **new** `Task` that is already completed, not the `Task` returned from `SendMails`.

Nothing is awaiting the completion of `SendMails`.

Just await the `Task` returned from the method:

```
bool result = await SendMails(formCollection["email"], formCollection["name"], pdfPath, imgPath);
```

The `await` keyword unwraps the `Task.Result` for you.